# VB.Net insert/select from one table to another error

Tags: sql, vb.net, parameters

I'm trying to Select * from tbl1 and insert it into tbl1_DEL. Basically if user wants to delete a record, i will first insert it into _DEL table before I delete the actual record in case it was done in error. Here's my code so far...

```
    queryD = "Insert Into tbl1_DEL "
    queryD = queryD & " SELECT * from Tbl1 WHERE IdClient = @IdClient"

    cmd.CommandText = queryD
    cmd.Connection = Conn
    Conn.Open()

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@IDClient", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = 17 'Just testing here with hardcoded IDClient

    rowAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

I wonder How I'd be able to continue on with this and basically do something like ....

```
    if rowAffected <>0 then 
    Delete * from Tbl1 where IDClient = 17 'parametized as it is with the Insert/Select above
    End if
```

I'm wondering if it can be something to do with the parameter since the datatype for that field is Numeric(18,0).

This is the error I keep getting...

> Column name or number of supplied values does not match table
>   definition.

Comment: The way that is usually done is with a `Deleted` or `Active` flag of some sort so you *dont* have to duplicate data like that

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing the delete but if you are using the same cmd instance, then you shouldn't add a new parameter.

Comment: so basically just do cmd.ExecuteNonQuery for both Insert/Select & Delete?

Comment: I guess I just want to make sure first that the record was inserted into the _Del tbl prior to deleting it. If I check the rowAffected, then I am certain that I can go ahead with Delete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the structures of tbl1_DEL and Tbl1 are different.

Either sync the structures or specify the field list (recommended)

```
Insert into tbl1_DEL (Fld1,Fld2...) 
 Select Fld1,Fld2...
  From  Tbl1 
  Where dClient = @IdClient
```

Per your comment

```
 Insert into tbl1_DEL
     Select *,TheOtherField = GetDate()    -- Assuming the one extra field is the last
      From  Tbl1 
      Where dClient = @IdClient
```

Comment: they are identical with the exception one of field in _Del table where you enter the current date - field name is DeletedOn

Comment: @Bobski That one field will generate the error.   If for example the last field  Insert into tbl1_DEL Select *,GetDate() from Tbl1

Comment: what if the date gets automatically entered into the field when record gets inserted. I think there is an option like that in sqlserver

Comment: @Bobski It sound like the other field has a default of GetDate().  See updated